# how do i read data from firebase realtime database in react-native using hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist, react-native-firebase

below is what I have done

```
useEffect(() => {
        database()
        .ref(`/User/`)
        .on('value', function(snapshot) {
          const list = [];
          snapshot.val(doc => {
            const { name, email} = snapshot.val();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              name,
              email,
            });
          });                



          
          setUsers(list);
          setLoading(false);
    
          console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
        });
  
    
        
    }, [userId]);
```

it shows the information from the database on the console, but it doesn't show on the app, doing this for firebase firestore works fine, but its not loading any information to the app page

below is how I have used flatlist and list.item tags to show the data from the database in the app

```
<FlatList
data={users}
ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Divider />}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Room', { thread: item })}
  >
    <List.Item
      title={item.name}
      description={item.email}
      titleNumberOfLines={1}
      titleStyle={styles.listTitle}
      descriptionStyle={styles.listDescription}
      descriptionNumberOfLines={1}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

/>

I am using the latest versions of react-native and firebase

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to pass a callback to `snapshot.val()` again.

It should be :

```js
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    var userKey = userSnapshot.key;
    var userData = userSnapshot.val();
    // userData['id'] = userKey;
    users.push(userData); 
  });
});
```

You can also try this library https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks.

Comment: Good catch. 1) It's `snapshot.forEach` indeed, not `snapshot.val` and 2) you'll want to get the `val()` of the iterator, as otherwise you're getting `/User/name` and `/User/email` every time.

Comment: users.push(id, userData);  this is what worked, thanks for the clarification 

Comment: anytime the list updates, it forms another array that adds to the previous array, how can i make it to reurn just one array with the updated information

Comment: @RaphaelInyang you can empty the array before snapshot.forEach ; Something like users = []

Answer (score 0):

```
 database()
          .ref(`/User/`)
          .once('value', function(snapshot) {  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
const id = userSnapshot.key;
const userData = userSnapshot.val();
  userData['id'] = id;
users.push(id, userData);  });});
```

this is what worked, the flatlist requires an id to be passed, thanks so much, those who helped out